# Doubts in blackberrycontentHandler

Tags: blackberry

i am trying to playing music file,using content handler,and this is code syntax i used

//Create invocation

```
Invocation invocation =
      new Invocation(filePath,null,BlackBerryContentHandler.ID_MEDIA_CONTENT_HANDLER);

    // Get the registry object
       Registry registry = Registry.getRegistry("net.rim.device.api.content.BlackBerryContentHandler");//here i changed to my own file

    //Invoke the content handler.
       registry.invoke(invocation);
```

When the application runs.it navigates  to media application screen,but it just stays out there,and can't play music or media file ,Any ideas what could be problem?

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and its working fine for me

```
Invocation invocation = new Invocation("file:///SDCard/B.mp3",
                        null, BlackBerryContentHandler.ID_MEDIA_CONTENT_HANDLER);
Registry.getRegistry(getClass().getName()).invoke(invocation);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your input ,i am trying to play a streaming file,your suggestions on it

Comment: for streaming start browser with rtsp url.
BrowserSession visit = Browser.getDefaultSession();
    visit.displayPage("rtsp://stream.the.sk/live/musicbox/musicbox-hm.3gp");

Comment: hello Vivart,I tried that way also.But i want the Streaming music or videos  files to be played via this blackberrycontenthandler.SO i am looking for it.